# How to use a function's argument as an object of another object inside of the function?

Tags: python, class

I've been stuck on this for a long time (like literally weeks), I've completed everything else in the code but this. I've also researched a lot but can't get anywhere near the solution. The only reason I waited a week to come here is because I wanted to solve this myself, but now, I give up!

Now, suppose I have the following code:

```
class test:
  def meth1(self, obj):
    self.hello = {}
    return self.hello.obj()
  def meth2(self):
      test.meth1(self, 'keys')
```

Now, when I create an instance and try to call the method `meth2`like this:

```
x = test()
x.meth2()
```

It gives me an error for obvious reasons. How can I get it do what I want-- pass an argument to a function and use that argument as an object of another object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
def meth1(self, obj):
    self.hello = {}
    return getattr(self.hello, obj)()
```

`getattr(a, b)` is equivalent to `a.b` (where `b` in the second case is the string that the `b` of the first case holds). In this case, `a` is `self.hello` and `b` is `obj`. From your snippet, it looks like you want to *call* the `obj` attribute as opposed to returning it directly, which is why we have a `()` at the end.

---

```
>>> class test:
...     def meth1(self, obj):
...         self.hello = {}
...         return getattr(self.hello, obj)()
...     def meth2(self):
...         return test.meth1(self, 'keys')
... 
>>> x = test()
>>> x.meth2()
[]
```

Comment: OK! I had actually forgot about getattr because I was never able to _get_ it properly...? So, would you mind explaining me what's going on with that code?

I mean, I know that it's similar to saying `self.hello.obj` but what difference does it make?

Comment: @AkshatTripathi Sure, I added a small explanation. Let me know if there is anything you still don't understand.

Comment: But what difference does it make? The code you wrote: `getattr(self.hello, obj)()` is equivalent to `self.hello.obj()`, still, when I try the latter one, it raises an exception, why so?

Comment: @AkshatTripathi They're not exactly equivalent in the sense you're thinking of. `obj` is a string here, and we say it's equivalent to `self.hello.*obj*()` where `*obj*` is replaced by the string `obj` holds. So, if `obj` is `'keys'`, then `getattr(self.hello, obj)` would be `self.hello.keys`. You wrote `self.hello.obj()`, which has *nothing* to do with the `obj` argument; it just tried to call the `obj` attribute of `self.hello`, and fails because there isn't one.

Comment: Got it, life saver! Thanks so much. :)